# Can I use rails console to identify unique seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not even sure if this is (a) something that can be done or (b) something I need to be concerned about. I had a project to write a `seeds.rb` file for seeing a RoR app with test data. My file is below:

```
require 'random_data'

50.times do
Post.create!(
    title: RandomData.random_sentence,
    body: RandomData.random_paragraph
)
end
posts = Post.all

100.times do
Comment.create!(
    post: posts.sample,
    body: RandomData.random_paragraph
)
end

unique_post = {
title: 'unique title',
body: 'unique body'
}

unique_post_id = Post.find_or_create_by!(unique_post)

unique_comment = {
post: unique_post_id,
body: "unique comment"
}

Comment.find_or_create_by!(unique_comment)

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{Post.count} posts created"
puts "#{Comment.count} comments created"
puts "#{unique_post.count} unique posts created"
puts "#{unique_comment.count} unique comments total"
```

Everything works fine. Resulting messages are:

```
Seed finished
251 posts created
501 comments created
2 unique posts created
2 comments total
```

I have two questions:

1. Why did I end up with 2 unique posts and 2 unique comments?
2. Can I use the rails console to identify those unique posts and
   comments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are seeing 2 unique posts and comments is because you're counting the hash keys of the object attributes, not the created object(s)..

```
{ key1: 123, key2: 456, key3: 789 }.count
=> 3
```

You can use Rails console to query for those unique posts/comments by just querying the table: `Comment.find_by(title: 'unique title')`